# Flag panel shows duplicate/off-topic on own question

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

When clicking the flag button on your own post, it allows you to select reasons such as off-topic/duplicate, when you already are able to vote to close your own question:

[image]

Since you could vote to close many of your own questions (and make them duplicates on purpose), it's likely someone might abuse this for either the Deputy or Marshal badges.  Even if that's not the case, it's still redundant - the other box will take care of any edge cases.

EDIT: note that I'm specifically talking about why that option is available through the flag panel when you are able to do something similar (and without moderator intervention) by voting to close your own question.

Comment: but don't you get marks against you for each of your questions/answers being flagged as negative - ie offtopic/dupe/rubbish/etc? Which can and does ultimately lead to your not able to ask/answer questions - I presume the latter would come well before any benefit of cheating the system.

Comment: @James: I'm not aware of any particular punishment system (apart from downvotes from the community, if any) that punishes people who posts lots of simple (often duplicate posts).

Comment: There is autoban that can be triggered for posting offtopics. But it shouldn't really hit users humble enough to be willing to flag own posts.

Comment: `it's likely someone might abuse this for either the Deputy or Marshal badges` How likely? If someone wants to flag a post just so they can get the Deputy or Marshall badge, they have over 5 million to choose from that *aren't* their own question.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: okay, _maybe_ that might be a bit less likely than I implied.  However, I'd like to think that we wouldn't leave an easy avenue of trouble open if we don't need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not actually any bug in there. If you open the flagging dialog when you have the ability to vote to close something, then selecting that option will actually redirect you through the vote-to-close dialog. Submitting the form will instead cast a close vote, rather than a flag.

I headed over to Gaming.SE to illustrate this, since I don't have full vote-to-close privileges there, but do have the privilege to vote-to-close my own questions (your same situation).

Notice the difference between the main flag dialog:

> [image: Main flag dialog]

And the dialog box you see when you've selected "it does not belong here" on **your own question**:

> [image: Close dialog inside flag dialog]

And the dialog box you see when you've selected "it does not belong here" on **some other question**:

> [image: Actually flagging to close]

Answer (score 2):

Yes it shows.

Why shouldn't it? It is possible that, during research, OP realized his question is really a duplicate of some older, hard to find one he missed earlier. I did it myself once or twice.

Flagging yourself as off-topic makes less sense, but take Drupal Answers - sometimes during research (tests suggested in comments) it comes out it was really a server issue all the time, off topic all right. If someone is willing to let 3k+ vote, again, why shouldn't he be able to?

If there is no real reason to forbid something, and UI is not cluttered, options should stay.

Comment: I'm referring to why this is still there, even when there is a vote-to-close option: if I didn't make that clear I'll edit the question.